# Out of memory training CNN-LSTM with GPU in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm, sentiment-analysis

Currently, I want to compile my hybrid CNN-LSTM model for sentiment analysis, but I got the following error

```
OOM when allocating tensor with shape[9051,300] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc [Op:RandomUniform]
```

This my GPU list, where I want to use the RTX one:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
 device_type: "CPU"
 memory_limit: 268435456
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 13057500645716466504,
 name: "/device:GPU:0"
 device_type: "GPU"
 memory_limit: 44957696
 locality {
   bus_id: 1
   links {
   }
 }
 incarnation: 6095838710984840352
 physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: NVIDIA RTX A6000, pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0, compute capability: 8.6",
 name: "/device:GPU:1"
 device_type: "GPU"
 memory_limit: 10648354816
 locality {
   bus_id: 1
   links {
   }
 }
 incarnation: 10826802477734196135
 physical_device_desc: "device: 1, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:09:00.0, compute capability: 6.1"]
```

this is my code:

```
# Build hybrid CNN-LSTM model
def build_cnn_lstm_model(num_words, embedding_vector_size, embedding_matrix, max_sequence_length):
    # Input layer
    input_layer = Input(shape=(max_sequence_length,))

    # Word embedding
    embedding_layer = Embedding(input_dim=num_words,
                              output_dim=embedding_vector_size,
                              weights=[embedding_matrix],
                              input_length=max_sequence_length)(input_layer)

    # CNN model
    # Bigrams extraction
    bigrams_convolution_layer = Conv1D(filters=256,
                                     kernel_size=2,
                                     strides=1,
                                     padding='valid',
                                     activation='relu')(embedding_layer)
    bigrams_max_pooling_layer = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2,
                                           strides=1,
                                           padding='valid')(bigrams_convolution_layer)

    # Trigrams extraction
    trigrams_convolution_layer = Conv1D(filters=256,
                                     kernel_size=3,
                                     strides=1,
                                     padding='valid',
                                     activation='relu')(bigrams_max_pooling_layer)
    trigrams_max_pooling_layer = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2,
                                           strides=1,
                                           padding='valid')(trigrams_convolution_layer)

    # Fourgrams extraction
    fourgrams_convolution_layer = Conv1D(filters=256,
                                      kernel_size=4,
                                      strides=1,
                                      padding='valid',
                                      activation='relu')(trigrams_max_pooling_layer)
    fourgrams_max_pooling_layer = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2,
                                            strides=1,
                                            padding='valid')(fourgrams_convolution_layer)

    # Fivegrams extraction
    fivegrams_convolution_layer = Conv1D(filters=256,
                                      kernel_size=5,
                                      strides=1,
                                      padding='valid',
                                      activation='relu')(fourgrams_max_pooling_layer)
    fivegrams_max_pooling_layer = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2,
                                            strides=1,
                                            padding='valid')(fivegrams_convolution_layer)

    # Dropout layer
    dropout_layer = Dropout(rate=0.5)(bigrams_max_pooling_layer)

    # LSTM model
    lstm_layer = LSTM(units=128,
                      activation='tanh',
                      return_sequences=False,
                      dropout=0.3,
                      return_state=False)(dropout_layer)

    # Batch normalization layer
    batch_norm_layer = BatchNormalization()(lstm_layer)

    # Classifier model
    dense_layer = Dense(units=10, activation='relu') (lstm_layer)
    output_layer = Dense(units=3, activation='softmax')(dense_layer)

    cnn_lstm_model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)

    return cnn_lstm_model

with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
    sinovac_cnn_lstm_model = build_cnn_lstm_model(SINOVAC_NUM_WORDS, 
                                                  SINOVAC_EMBEDDING_VECTOR_SIZE,
                                                  SINOVAC_EMBEDDING_MATRIX,
                                                  SINOVAC_MAX_SEQUENCE)
    sinovac_cnn_lstm_model.summary()

    sinovac_cnn_lstm_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                                   optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),
                                   metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Strangely, I used the GPU:1 that is the GTX one, it worked
The GTX 1080Ti one is obviously has fewer memory than the RTX A6000 one, but why it produced Out Of Memory error when compiled and trained with the RTX A6000 ?
Any solution?

Comment: Isn't your device list saying that `"/device:GPU:1"` is the A6000; therefore `"/device:GPU:0"` would be the 1080Ti (your list cuts off at that point where it is about to give the `name` of the `1080Ti`).

Comment: Yes , I think I had my GPU name wrong, I ended up using the GPU:1 , thanks

Comment: I just expanded my comment into an answer, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the `physical_device_desc` calls it `device: 0`, it is the name under that, `name: "/device:GPU:1"` entry that is used.  Therefore even though the 1080Ti calls itself `device: 1` in the `physical_device_desc` field, it is actually `"/device:GPU:0".

In other words, use `with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):` to use the 1080Ti, and `with tf.device('/device:GPU:1'):` to get the A6000.

That sounds potentially fragile, but I just had a poke around in Tensorflow docs, and there seems no built-in function to identify a GPU by model name. So you'd need to run through the list of devices, and match against that physical device name (or simply find the the one with most memory) to get the "GPU:nnn" name you need.

Comment: Yes, I think that would be make sense, thanks, now I can use the GPU properly, turns out I use the GPU:0 and it ended up tensorflow to use the RTX one